# map top level JSON String array Object Mapper

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

How to mpa top level JSON String Array

> JSON Response from server

```
[
        "tag1",
        "tag2",
        "tag3",
        "tag4",
        "tag5",
        "tag6"
]
```

I am Using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#generic-objects) Swift

Comment: You need to provide some examples of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solved it without ObjectMapper:

On response from server cast the raw **JSON** into **String array**

```
...
..
    case .Success(let request, _, _):
                self.request = request.responseJSON{ json in
                    if json.result.isSuccess {
                        if let tags =  json.result.value as? [String]{ // Cast it as String Array
                            self.remoteTags.removeAll()
                            tags.forEach{self.remoteTags.append($0)}

                        }
                        self.reloadData()
                    }
                }
...
..
```

**[Note: Using Alamofire for Network Operations]**